# How to run cronjob on alternate weekday?

Tags: unix, cron

I have a script which runs everyday at 1.00 AM regularly for every day.

But On every alternate Wednesday I need to change the timings to 6.00 AM and which currently I am doing separately on every Tuesday Manually.

e.g

1. Wednesday Nov 09 2016 6.00 AM.
2. Wednesday Nov 23 2016 6.00 AM.
3. Wednesday Dec 07 2016 6.00 AM.

The main thing is for every Wednesday in between the job should be as per regular timings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this bash trick](https://serverfault.com/a/633272/239280) it could be done with 3 cron entries (possibly 2):

```
#Every day except Wednesdays at 1am
0 1 * * 0,1,2,4,5,6 yourCommand

#Every Wednesdays at 1am, proceeds only on even weeks
0 1 * * 3 test $((10#$(date +\%W)\%2)) -eq 0 && yourCommand

#Every Wednesdays at 6am, proceeds only on odd weeks
0 6 * * 3 test $((10#$(date +\%W)\%2)) -eq 1 && yourCommand
```

Change the `-eq`'s to 1 or 0 depending if you want to start with odd or even week. It should work according to your example, because Wednesday Nov 09 2016 6.00 AM is even.

Comment: can u pls explain command 0 1 * * 3 test $((10#$(date +\%W)\%2)) -eq 0 && yourCommand

Comment: Check the link in my answer, there is a detailed explanation of this trick. Basically, it gets a week number with `date +%W` and checks if the week is odd or even with modulo operation (`%2`). @VivekraoBhosale

Comment: there will be a problem if there will be 53 weeks in a year.

Comment: This situation is not very common (I think next is in 2020), if you'd want to check for that it gets more complicated. If the year has 53 weeks, execute on odd weeks, if it has 52 weeks, execute on even weeks (it's inverted). I think it'd be better to place it in a script as on one line it could get very confusing because it will probably contain an if statement. This command will give you number of weeks in current year: `$((10#$(date -d "$(date +%Y)1228" +%V)))`.